# Satake compactification for the moduli space of curves of genus $g$

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, moduli-space

I am using the book Compact Complex Surfaces by Wolf P. Barth,
Klaus Hulek, Chris A. M. Peters, Antonius Van de Ven. On p.220, this book says "It follows readily from the projectivity of the Satake compactification for the moduli space of curves of genus $g$ that there exist Kodaira fibrations with any given genus $g,g\ge3$."

But this book only gives the construction/description of the compactification for the moduli space of Abelian varieties: Satake's compactification, $\overline{\mathcal{S}_g/\Gamma_g}$ of the period domain is a normal projective variety, which is stratified by subvarieties $\overline{\mathcal{S}_g/\Gamma_g}=\mathcal{S}_g/\Gamma_g\cup \mathcal{S}_{g-1}/\Gamma_{g-1}\cup \mathcal{S}_1/\Gamma_1\cup\{pt\}$.

I wonder what the construction of the Satake compactification for the moduli space of curves of genus $g$ is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Satake compactification of the moduli space of curves $\mathcal M_g$ is the following: consider the image of $\mathcal M_g$  in $\mathcal A_g$ via the Torelli map $j$. Consider the Satake compactification of $\mathcal A_g$ as you describe. Then take the closure of $j(\mathcal M_g)$ in the Satake compactification. This is the Satake compactification of $\mathcal M_g$.
This is described briefly in Harris-Morrison's book on moduli of curves. The study of the map from the GIT compactification to the Satake compactification i carried on -to my knowledge-  in KNUDSEN, F. The projectivity of the moduli space of stable curves, I. Math. Stand., 39, 19-66, 1976. 11,Math. Stand., 52 161-199,

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's been a little long, so can I ask a naive question? Is $A_g$ just $S_g/\Gamma_g$?

Comment: I'm sorry I just stumbled upon this question recently... $A_g$ means there the coarse moduli space of principally polarized abelian varieties $\mathbb H_g/Sp$., where  $\mathbb H_g$ is the Siegel upper half plane and $Sp$ is the Symplectic group ${Sp} _{2g}(\mathbb Z )$

Comment: thank you for the explanation.